# Table size much bigger than actual data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've a table, let's call it `Roads` (changed not to reveal company stuff). This table stores the denormalised roads between places, with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.roads (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    'from' varchar NOT NULL,
    'to' varchar NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    metadata_id int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT roads_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT roads_from_to_key UNIQUE (from, to)
)
WITH (
    autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=0,
    autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit=1500
);
CREATE INDEX from_idx ON public.roads USING btree ('from');
CREATE INDEX updated_at_idx ON public.roads USING btree (updated_at);
CREATE INDEX to_idx ON public.roads USING btree ('to');
```

Places are denormalised for performance reasons when querying.

If I export all data as CSV, the file is merely 6MB. But on the DB this table is 12GB.

As you can see I added the autovacuum tuning to try to fix this, but it did not help.

The usage pattern is lots of updates that in the end change the timestamp. So I thought there must be a problem with autovacuum not catching up. This is an extermely large db, and autovacuum may be slow, but this is too much.

Why is this? Any suggestions? It can't be that the indexes are so big.

Comment: How did you measure the size of the table in the database?

Comment: As a side note: the CREATE TABLE as shown won't run because `from`  and `to` are reserved keywords  that will need to be quoted.

Comment: I changed names pretend they are ok. the table is in the db and to and from have different names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my tool does it, DBEAVER. not sure how. do you have any idea?

Comment: With many updates, you might want to change the fill factor. This can reduce the need for (auto) vacuum and improves update speeds. But 6MB vs 12GB is just crazy, something went seriously wrong in your database.

Comment: @gotch4  "DBeaver did it" is not an answer.  DBeaver does lots of things.  Which particular thing is it that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for such a table to be twice the size of the CSV file.

First, data are organized in 8kB blocks. There is a block header, and some space usually has to remain empty. There is more overhead than that: every row has a header of 23 bytes. This will account for most of the overhead. In addition to that, rows and many columns have to be aligned to certain memory boundaries, which leads to padding before and between columns. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html) for details.

Together with the three indexes, this can easily double the space requirements.

You can use `pg_relation_size()` to find out the size of the indexes on disk. Use `pg_table_size()` to find out the size of the table without the indexes.

Comment: I believe you misread. The csv is 6mb and the table shows as 12 Gb

Comment: Yes, I misread. Please assess where in the data directory the 12GB are and add that information to the question.